# Audio recording on website

Tags: php, flash, audio

Hey all, I'm building a website that is supposed to record and upload audio to a server and also be able to play said audio.

Currently I have a BB app that does the same, I record the audio in .amr format, send the bytes over to the server and convert it to an .mp3 file with ffmpeg.

How can I manage to record audio and save it in .mp3 format? With Flash, HTML or any other means.

My website is being built with PHP under the CakePHP framework.